# Incompatible pointer type error [C]

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-construction, types, arguments

I keep getting told that in this line of code passing argument from incompatible pointer type.
Here's the line of code:

```
if (linear_search (size_of_A, argv[i]))
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it? Here is the whole program:

```
int linear_search ( int size_of_A, char*argv[]){  
   int i;  
   i = 2;  
   while (i <= size_of_A - 1){  
      if (!strcmp (argv [1], argv[i])){  
      return 1;  
      }  
   }  
   return 0;  
}  

int main (int argc, char*argv []){  
   int size_of_A = argc - 2;  
   int i = 2;  
      if (linear_search (size_of_A, argv)){  
         printf ("%s not found\n", argv [1]);  
         return 1;  
      } else{  
         printf ("%s found\n", argv[1]);  
         return 0;  
      }  
      i = i + 1;  
   }  
}
```

Ok, that fixes the warning, but now when I run the program through the compiler nothing happens. It's supposed to tell me if the first argument is repeated or not.
For example the output would look like:

```
./a 3 hso 8 3  
3 found
```

Comment: That's what the top function is supposed to be...

Comment: Hey, I've seen this code before :-)

Comment: There were quite a few issues in your code. I pointed these out in your other post. Take a look at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750265/how-to-search-arguments-to-find-a-match-to-the-first-argument-in-c-language/750313#750313>

Answer (score 4):

linear_search is expecting a data type "`char **`".  You are passing in `argv[i]`, which is just a `char*`.  Try passing in "argv" like this:

```
if (linear_search(size_of_A, argv))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a logic error in `linear_search`. You have a while loop based on the value of `i`, but `i` never changes. You might be missing a `i++;` instruction.

Also (although this won't change your program's behaviour): the variable `i` in `main` is never really used. You can remove it and the `i = i + 1;` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a parameter (the second one) to the `linear_search` function which does not match the expected type of the argument. argv[i] has the type `char *`, which is commonly referred to as a string, while the `linear_search` function expects `char * []`, which is an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your linear search function only compares argv[1] with argv[2] as *i* is never incremented. A possible solution (using a for loop instead of a while, which is more common) would be:

```
int linear_search ( int size_of_A, char*argv[]){  
   int i = 0;  // should always initialize in construction
   for ( i = 2; i < size_of_A; ++i ) {
      if (!strcmp (argv [1], argv[i])){  
        return 1;  
      }  
   }  
   return 0;  
}
```

Variable *i* is never really used in main, you can safely remove the two lines that deal with it.

Comment: Could you please the two commented code lines? I understand it is done for simplifying comprising in this case, but it is a very bad smell (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114342/what-are-code-smells-what-is-the-best-way-to-correct-them/114576#114576). +1 from me when you remove those.

Comment: The reason is to make clear the changes from the original question code to this solution. In real code that should not stay there.

Answer (score 0):

Your function expects a `char*[]` (which should be equivalent in this case to `char**`). However, by calling it with

```
linear_search (size_of_A, argv[i])
```

you are just passing a `char*` as argument (since `[i]` dereferences one pointer). From what I see in your code you could try using

```
linear_search (size_of_A, argv+i)
```

but I'm not quite sure whether that will yield the intended behaviour. Still too early to understand C :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the logic of your program but compiler error is solved.
See this:

int main (int argc, char*argv []){

```
int size_of_A = argc - 2;  
int i = 2;  
if (linear_search (size_of_A, argv[])){  
     printf ("%s not found\n", argv [1]);  
     return 1;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int linear_search ( int size_of_A, char*argv[]){
```

`char*argv[]` means "pointer to an array of char"; as a function call parameter, that's the same as `char**`.

argv *is* a `char**`, but `argv[i]` is a `char*`, because C defines `argv[i]` as `*(argv + i )` or, in English "dereference (argv plus i)". Dereferencing a `char**` leaves you with a `char*`, and that''s not what `linear_search` is declared to take.

Take a look [here if you're still confused.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750091/pointer-to-an-array-of-structs-and-getting-memory-c/750108#750108)
`

Answer (score 0):

Your linear_search() accepts an "array of strings" (pointer to array of characters), while you are passing it a "string" (argv[i]). What you want to do I think is to call linear_search as:

```
if (linear_search (size_of_A, (argv + i)))
```

Although I do not completely understand the logic of your program... Are you trying to search argv[1] in the later arguments...?

Comment: ya, I'm supposed to see if argv[1] is repeated later on.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be great place to use the fact that `argv is NULL-terminated. You don't need to pass the count of items in it, but just do like this:`

```
/* Searches through the NULL-aterminated array for the.
 * given needle string. Returns 1 if found, 0 if not.
*/
int linear_search (char **argv, const char *needle)
{
  int i;

  for(i = 0; argv[i] != NULL; i++)
  {
     if(strcmp(argv[i], needle) == 0)
       return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Btw, I recommend comparing the return value of strcmp() nagainst literal 0, rather than using the ! notation, since the return value is in fact not boolean; it returns a int that expresses the relation between the compared elements.

I realize the use of ! here is common enough to be almost idiomatic, since many people think that C must always be as terse as possible, but ... I still recommend against it.

Answer (score 0):

**oldfart:** Beware of `strcmp` and all unlimited string functions (like strcpy--but be careful with strncpy: it doesn't add a trailing NULL).

**youngun:**  But it's ok since `argv` has a bunch of NULL terminated strings!

**of:** That way of thinking leads to a heaping helping of buffer overflow.  `argv` was initialized with NULLS.  But it could have changed since then.

**y:** But this is a small program and it will never happen.

**of:** Sure. Programs grow and 'never' happens more often than you think.

**y:** OK, well Mr. Paranoid, what size should I use for the limit on my `strncmp`?  There's no obvious number to use!  Are you suggesting I make something up?

**of:** See limits.h, in particular `ARG_MAX` and `_POSIX_ARG_MAX` for possible maximum values.  You could use smaller values if you so desire.  If you do, **document it**.

**y:** So I should write `strncmp( arg, target, 5000 )`?  OK, mister paranoid.

**of:** Don't do that!  `#define APP_MAX_ARG 5000` and then use `strncmp( arg, target, APP_MAX_ARG )`.  Don't get me started on magic numbers.  Kids these days.

**of:** Hey, kid, *get off my lawn*.